# Use of a phrase : debt of one year

Tags: prepositions

> He decided to pay his debt of one year.

Is use of “of” idiomatic in this sentence or should I use different preposition? I mean for example, someone borrowed a money from someone one year ago, and now he has decided to re-pay that debt of one year.

Can we express this situation using the phrase “debt of one year” or should we say something else? As I am not a native speaker, I think it would be impossible for me to say a phrase like "his debt of one year's standing which my teacher said." This is why I wondered if my phrase, “debt of one year”, can be understood easily by a native speaker or anyone who knows English.

Comment: _Debt of_ would normally be followed by the sum of money owed. I don't see anything wrong with _debt of one year's standing_.

Comment: This unusual sense of 'of' equates to 'which/who has existed/been such for' and must be followed by an actual timespan (usually lengthy) ('one year', 'many years' ...). As Kate says, your longer phrase (from which the shorter version probably arises) is normal. // Almost 5 000 000 Google hits claimed for "a friend of many years" including say "The loss of a friend of many years brings not only absence ...".

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  Does the debt correspond to a loan agreed on condition of being repaid within one year?  Or is it an open-ended loan which the borrower has decided to repay at the end of a year?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That seems like a substantial answer. Wanna make it official?

Comment: @Andy Bonner I would have done, but couldn't find dictionary backing. They miss some usages (having different numbers of subsenses proves this).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'll be darned, I can't find an exact one either. [These](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/of-many-five-ten-etc-years-standing) [come close](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/of-many-years-standing).

Comment: @Andy Bonner I'd post the first.